# Runtime Error '3709' while accesing SQL database in VB6

Tags: sql, vb6, user-permissions

I have a VB6 application which someone wrote, which does not work for only some users who try to use it.

This is the code running which returns an error:

```
 On Error GOTO error_handler
 ..
 Set db = New ADODB.Connection
 db.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=****;Password=****; Initial Catalog=***;Data Source=****,1433"
 error_handler:
 If db.Error.count then
 strDBErrors = "No access to Main Database."
 For Each err In db.errors
  strDBErrors = strDBErrors & vbCrLf & err.Description
 Next
 MsgBox strDBErrors
```

After this code runs, I get two Boxes of error. One which states a Runtime Error 3709, And the other which has Two lines: one of it is my Custom error message, and the second if this: "Logon Failed for user *the user*".

This only happens to one user on a specific computer on which this program is installed. It does not happen on any other computer with any other user.
I tried reinstalling the program with that user on that computer, but it did not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue to me...

Comment: Narrow it down to computer vs user. Can that user run the app on a different machine? Can another user run the app on that machine?

Comment: It has been narrowed down to that specific user - this user can't run the program on any machine, where as any other user can run it on any machine.

Comment: I looked all over the Active Directory properties of that specific user - but I could not find any properties which where different from any other user that had the program running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what the problem was,
but I just erased the user on Active Directory and created it again, and it worked.
The user wasn't a member of any deny groups though.